# How to cite a poem, with a quote that is on multiple non-contiguous lines?

Tags: citation

I have to cite a quote from a poem that is on multiple lines that are not next to eachother. How would I do this?

"This is my quote" (line1 - line 2) OR "This is my quote" (line1 .. line2) ?

Comment: I think it's (line1-line2)

Comment: I think I've seen  *line1\ line 2\ ...* using the backslash character-space as the delimiter.  Need to check that again on a reliable source, though. Btw, have you asked on writersSE?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you are using MLA.
It would have to be line 1... line 2 if words are omitted. The ellipsis (...) in quotations suggests the omission of text.
If you are omitting complete lines, use extended ellipsis about the length of the line or lines that you are omitting.

I will offer this advice with some reservation because without knowing the poem you are quoting or the proximity of one line to the next, I cannot be sure whether or not it would be better to use the quote as you have suggested, or of it would be clearer to introduce them separately within a paragraph that presents your argument as it relates to the two separate, yet related, sections of text.
If the lines are close in proximity and/or closely related, use the ellipses. If they are in completely different stanzas or loosely related, introduce them separately within the same paragraph.